# How to simplify Django filter like C/JS conditional operator

Tags: python, django, django-models

here is my query,

```
get_emp = Employee.objects.get(id='emp_id').name if Employee.objects.filter(name='emp_id') else None
```

this is my scenario... this working fine.. but my query is to simply this even more.. is it possible?

because here i am doing the same query twice in condition check and to fetch value. is it possible to make it single?

i know to define it separately and do as i want like,

```
emp_id = Employee.objects.filter(id='emp_id')
get_emp = emp_id[0].name if emp_id else None
```

but i want to do it in first method... is it possible?

i tried this too,

```
get_emp = Employee.objects.filter(id='emp_id').first()
```

but i want `emp_name` after querying was done .. so above wont work will through an error

I want to do something like this,

```
get_emp = Employee.objects.get(id='emp_id').first().name ? null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `first()`:

```
get_emp = Employee.objects.filter(id='emp_id').first()
```

It should behave like you want. But try:)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution can be `get_object_or_None()` from [**django-annoying**](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#get_object_or_none-function):

```
get_emp = get_object_or_None(Employee, id='emp_id')

if not get_emp:
    ...
```